# How to cover TypeORM @Column decorator with Jest unit testing?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs, typeorm

I want to Unit and e2e test my applications as much as possible and my goal is a coverage of 101%. Problem right now with my setup is, that the @Column decorator from typeorm uses an arrow function to set a default value like the current timestamp on a database update. This arrow function is not covered with jest test coverage. Message is: `statement not covered`

I run the code coverage with: `jest --coverage`.
My versions:

```
"jest": "^24.9.0",
"typeorm": "^0.2.20"
```

Jest configuration within package.json:

```json
{
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "coverageDirectory": "../build/coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "branches": 80,
        "functions": 80,
        "lines": 80,
        "statements": -10
      }
    }
  },
}
```

My entity looks like this:

```js
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class Role {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    tenantId: number;

    @Column({ type: 'timestamp', update: false, default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()' })
    createdAt: Date;

    @Column({ type: 'timestamp', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()', onUpdate: 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()' })
    updatedAt: Date;
}
```

Coverage for this entity:

[image]

Comment: You are the hero we need in these dark times.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue with GraphQL decorators. As all of these are functions, what you can do is create a file that holds all of the functions you'll be using, name them, and export them, so that you can actually test them as well and get the coverage with Jest. (The tests should literally be something like `expect(namedFunction).toBe('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()')` or very similar. <s>For an example [you can see my function here](https://github.com/jmcdo29/zeldaPlay/blob/master/apps/api/src/app/models/gqlReturns.ts) and [my tests here](https://github.com/jmcdo29/zeldaPlay/blob/master/apps/api/src/app/models/graphql-returns.spec.ts).</s>

## EDIT 11/03/2020

The code examples are no more. That being said, you can do things like

```js
export const returnString = () => String;

@Query(returnString)
```

for GraphQL. A test for this would look like

```js
expect(returnString()).toBe(String);
```

Comment: Amazing. Coverage is 100% now without those annoying "ignore" comments <3

Comment: Only problem left is the missing return type of those newly created functions. E.g.:

```export const returnString = () => String;```

I can't provide `: String` as return type because it moans about missing methods of type *StringConstructor*

Comment: You should still be able to do something like `expect(returnString()).toBe(String)`. I've got that running in my test classes without a problem

Comment: Thanks for the updates @JayMcDoniel. This was enough to get me to a solution that worked for my case.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution that worked for me, based off of @JayMcDoniel's answer.

- database type: `postgreSQl`
- testing: `jest/chai`

Functions class:

```
  export abstract class EntityDefaultFunctions {
    public static defaultNull = (): string => 'NULL';
    public static defaultZero = (): string => '0';
  }
```

Tests:

```
  expect(EntityDefaultFunctions.defaultNull()).to.equal('NULL');
  expect(EntityDefaultFunctions.defaultZero()).to.equal('0');
```

Example Entity Column definition:

```
  @Column('text', {
    default: EntityDefaultFunctions.defaultNull,
    name: 'somePropertyName'
  })
```